# HashRouter keeps taking me home

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So i'm trying to create my portfolio using react and hosting with github pages, i read that for github pages you need to use the HashRouter from react-router-dom, however, all my links keep taking me to my home pages as opposed to their path.

I noticed the path looks like this in the browser: http://localhost:3000/MyHumber#/

app.js:

```
<HashRouter>
        <div>
        <Navigation />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/MyHumber" component={MyHumber} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
```

Comment: Add exact to the `/` path `<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />`

Comment: Hi, Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use exact path and do not forget about closing slash

```
 <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />   
 <Route exact path="/MyHumber/" component={MyHumber} />
```